# Rotate vector by a random little amount

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, rotations

Suppose there is a vector $v = (v_x, v_y, v_z)$.

I want to rotate this vector by a random little amount (let's say at most $10º$). How can I do that?

For better visualization, suppose $v$ begins in the middle of a sphere and I want to move $v$'s end to any point of the red circle.

[image]

Comment: Just add any tiny vector to it and normalize to ensure it's on the sphere. If you want to make sure it's within some angle tolerance then check the angle using the dot product formulation.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I could, but I would like to tune this value I mentioned ($10º$) so that I can test it for different values. Just adding a random little vector could indeed do the job but then I would have to evaluate the angle between the old and new vectors and check if it is inside my desired range.

Comment: The circle will have a radius and any vector shorter than that radius will do so you should be able to find a fixed limit to the length that exactly bounds the region you're interested in. Do you need a closed form solution or is an analytical one good enough?

Comment: I just used the sphere and the circle for better visualization. The circle is the projection of all possible rotations for $v$ in the surface of the sphere. Obviously the points inside the circle should also be possible.

Comment: It's sufficient to solve this on the unit sphere and then scale appropriately since scaling is conformal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find two mutually perpendicular unit vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ that are also perpendicular to your vector $v$

Thus the vectors $u_1, u_2, \dfrac{v}{\| v \|} $ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Let the rotation matrix $R$ be defined as follows:

$R = \left[ u_1, u_2, \dfrac{v}{\| v\| } \right]$

Then vectors $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are expressed in this basis as $y$ as follows

$x = R y $

Note that the $y$ corresponding to your vector $v$ is

$ y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \|v\| \end{bmatrix}$

Now using spherical coordinates, we can express your desired vector as

$ y =r \begin{bmatrix} \sin \theta \cos \phi \\ \sin \theta \sin \phi \\ \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} $

where from the conditions of the problem $0 \le \theta \le 10^\circ $ and $\phi$ is arbitrary.  And $r=\|v\|$.

And finally the new vector in the world coordinates is given by

$ x = R y $